# failed to create symbolic link 'public/storage/public': File exists

Tags: laravel, gitlab-ci

i am installing composer `composer install` using .gitlab-ci.yml.

installation was successfully done with this message:

```
Package manifest generated successfully.
```

but I got these errors:

```
 Method Composer\Config::disableProcessTimeout is not callable, can 
    not call post-install-cmd script
 >ln -sr storage/app/public public/storage
 ln: failed to create symbolic link 'public/storage/public': File 
    exists
 Script ln -sr storage/app/public public/storage handling the post- 
    install-cmd event returned with error code 1
 Running after_script
 Uploading artifacts for failed job
 ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

how would I can fix it

thanks

Comment: Sounds like you might have an ownership / permissions issue. Have you tried running 'php artisan storage:link' to create that symlink manually?

Comment: yes I did it
he shows me this message
`The "public / storage" directory already exists.`

Answer (score 1):

A Linux `symlink` cannot be created if the target directory or file already exists. Hence your error message.

If you are planning on linking your `storage/app/public` directory, you need to do so before any files are added to that directory (build files for example).

Something which has caught me out before when using version control software like `git`, is that sometimes a directory you may want to `symlink` on a production environment has accidentally been commited into the repository.

For now, you may want to rename the target directory and re-run your command. Then copy the content of your renamed directory into the `/storage/app/public/` directory